# Выполнить функцию по запросу с сервера

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

Как выполнить функцию по запросу с сервера?

Например, сервер шлёт функцию `Add(1,1,1)` и она выполняется уже непосредственно в клиенте (в реалтайме).

Хотелось бы увидеть решение **не привязанное** к определенной функции (т.е., чтобы можно было указать имя любой существующей функции с нужными аргументами и она выполнилась у клиента).

Comment: вас интересует именно Unity реализация, через их мультиплеер HLAPI? Или общая для C#?

Comment: @M. Green зависит от того что будет более оптимизированней, но хотелось бы увидеть Unity реализацию